# parsing a string based on specified identifiers

Tags: python, string, parsing

Let's say that I have the following text:

```
input = "one aaa and bbb two bbbb er ... // three cccc"
```

I would like to parse this into a group of variables that contain

```
criteria = ["one", "two", "three"]
v1,v2,v3 = input.split(criteria)
```

I know that the example above won't work, but is there some utility in python that would allow me to use this sort of approach?  I know what the identifiers will be in advance, so I would think that there has got to be a way to do this...

Thanks for any help,
jml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not terribly elegant but it works:

```
>>> s
'one aaa two bbbb three cccc'
>>> re.split(r"\s*(?:one|two|three)\s*", s)
['', 'aaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']
```

The `?:` keeps it from returning the delimiting identifiers in the results.

Answer (score 1):

So, so ugly, but it should do what you need:

```
i1 = iter(input.split())
i2 = iter(input.split())
next(i2)
strdict = dict(zip(i1, i2))
print operator.itemgetter(*criteria)(strdict)
```

Comment: very cool.  i don't think it's _that_ ugly!  i mean; consider this being done in c.  :)